# How to use eyeD3 for abcde since pep 668

Tags: debian, python3, ripping, abcde

How can I use eyeD3 in Debian 12 with abcde since pep 668?

I am trying to use abcde with output set to mp3 set in `.abcde.conf`. abcde does not find eyeD3, so I try to install. However, `pip3`/`pip` tell me to use virtual environments or install via `apt install python3-eyed3` as far as I understand. After installation of `python3-eyed3` however the path is still not found.

```
# apt install python3-eyed3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-eyed3 is already the newest version (0.9.7-1).
```

pip eyeD3 installation try. pip3 gives the same result.

```
# pip install eyeD3 
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

```
$ abcde
[ERROR] abcde: eyeD3 is not in your path.
[INFO] Define the full path to the executable if it exists on your system.
[INFO] Hint: sudo apt-get install
```

```
~$ cat /etc/debian_version 
12.5
```

I have had a look in [pep 668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) and [eyeD3 installation docs](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation). While understanding why the pep change happened I do not understand what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are bringing Python into your question, `abcde` does not use Python so installing `python3-eyed3` would not fix the error `[ERROR] abcde: eyeD3 is not in your path`.

You would want to install the `eyed3` package (`apt install eyed3`) and make sure it is available in your `PATH` to solve that error.

Comment: That is it. I only tried `apt install eyeD3` before and did not follow that path further.